Open source license more viral than GPL/AGPL
I am looking for an open-source license with an enlarged scope of when something is considered a derived work, compared to AGPL. Ideally it should be OSI approved, but following OSI requirements for a license to be considered OS is enough. It should include the following:

when something interacts with it over the network, e.g. via REST interface, the calling software should be considered derived work, and hence it would be required to be licensed under the license
when something interacts with it over standard OS interfaces - e.g. called from a shell, pipe etc.. it should be derived work as well

It should also require providing access to source code for any user of the software via network or other means - similar to AGPL section 13, but also for non-modified version of the software.
To summarize, I'm looking for something more viral than AGPL.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The fundamental problem is that you're trying to expand the definition of derived work.  But that's not yours to define; it's defined by copyright law.  If you can find a lawyer that will say the Berne Convention defines the Bourne shell, or a web browser, as "derived works" of your software, then good luck to you; but I doubt that you will.
You can certainly add additional terms to your license, which require more than the usual copyleft obligations of the licensee.  You wouldn't be the first person to do that; licences like the SSPL tried similar "land-grabs", but they have generally been held to be non-free (and thus, I note, outwith the scope of this site) as well as being wildly unpopular in the greater community.  Moreover, if you try that with (A)GPLv3, s7 treats those terms as additional restrictions, and says the licensee may simply ignore them.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

First, I am not a lawyer.
While I don't know of any such OSI approved license, it sounds like you could achieve something similar-ish (not the software being declared derivate work, but it having to be licensed in a compatible way).
But it's more of a cascading thing. You would have to ask the licensee to only re-license the source code with compatible terms (rather classical), to license any binary form with compatible terms, when they use the binary, to request and ensure that any other piece of software used to access it is licensed under compatible terms.
That would cause a lot of contamination, as for instance, a proxy could be used to access your software. You could extend your license to exclude "software that does not perform any processing to the data" or something like that.
Next, you'd have to talk to a lawyer about how that would work... If I use your code and somebody access my software including your code with a software that is not licensed in a compatible way, does that mean it's my fault? I asked them to use a complying software. If deemed my fault, you can sue me. That puts a legal risk on me, extra burden (what if it's a software at a customer of a customer of a customer?), I have an easy way to solve it: I won't use your software.
If it's not my fault, then what right do you have to go check if the customer of my customer uses a software with compatible licensing? Do you put in the license that by using your code, the licensee grants you a right to audit them, and must request of any users of their software that they grant you a right to audit them?
Me? Same result, I won't use your code.

I am a lawyer who practices copyright and open source law. I don’t think a license like this is in popular use, but it’s possible to create. And I believe it could be OSI compliant.
A license is just a type of contract. Specifically it’s a “license agreement,” and that word “agreement” is the tip off that it’s a contract.
You can put whatever language you want into the contract. In this case, it would likely pair with your terms of service (also a contract).
Just like a website can say “you can’t use this for illegal purposes,” you can say “you can’t use this service except as part of an OSI approved copyleft open source application.”
But what a lot of people don’t realize is that enforcing an open source license doesn’t necessarily do what they think it does. It doesn’t automatically relicense someone else’s code. Instead, it causes them to breach the contract. You then have the right to revoke the license or revoke the right to use the service and, in some cases, use the courts to get damages.
For example, a license for a commercial software may say it can only be used as part of a paid subscription. If you bootleg the software they can sue for monetary damages. This does happen now and then with open source software.
So the license you want will need to be created. This should be done by an attorney in your area. If you are in the U.S. that would be licensed in the state you live or do business in.

Not a lawyer but isn’t part of enforcement considering the likelihood of winning the case against alleged infringers? And if the license would make an already existent browser or server or framework an infringer, do you think (honest question; not a lawyer) that OP is likely to win such a case?

The dirty truth about copyright infringement lawsuits is that they typically are very expensive to litigate. If the infringer has insurance, then they’ll work out a deal. If not, then they just go bankrupt or hide under a rock. So “winning” cases like this isn’t as cool as it sounds. They also take a very long time. I started a case in May and it hasn’t even gotten to the part of the trial where the alleged infringer has had to respond yet.

So you want to gain rights to something that is not created by you and is actually not a derived work of yours. Let say someone opened a page using Google Chrome (using REST) and this should grant you rights to the person and to Google Chrome? I hope you feel the complications derived from this logic and your assumptions.
However you can restrict use of your own code. This could restrict derived works based on your open source. And you can "force" derived work to be open. You can also add some authentication, for example username and password. This way you can control who can use your resources and your further work.
However open source allows others to use same code within the license limits. And to set up own servers with own passwords. Here your input ends so you have no ownership over the work of someone else.
You could also stay with closed source. Ship binaries only with your own keys. Like Google android on production. Software is free and open but you must get a certificate from Google to use their service and host the app on their shop. While Android is open source (not everything) it does not include Gmail, apps store and other services. You can create your own ecosystem if you wish.


gain rights to something that is not created by you and is actually not a derived work of yours

No. My aim is - if you combine this software with other software (via linking, or via network, or other means), I want you to publish it under the same license, or forbid you to combine it (e.g. in case where you don't own the rights to e.g. Google Chrome).

You release it as open source. Anyone can use it to create their own. Then your license would not really apply... Unless you can prove that they cannot do this without your source. This could be difficult. And remember about much different law in US and in other parts of the world. You can request them to use same license and disallow using your own software. If you are able to prove that it is yours only and if someone would still want to use your code (I would not) then you can fight at the court... Normally you should create a closed source service and restrict API access

IANAL but I've been through a few rodeos. By simple definition any software that was written prior to your software could never be legally considered as a derived work. So you would be unable to apply such a condition to those softwares. And in general one of the foundational principles embodied in law is that if you cannot equally apply the law in all cases then the law is inapplicable for any case. A license that demands what you are asking for could not be enforced.

There was a lot of fuss about the SSPL, which is very similar to what the OP is asking for, but in all that fuss I never saw any serious suggestion that the licence was unenforceable against someone who'd accepted it.

@MadHatter, The problem arises when the license involves what is known as an adhesion contract. These are contracts in which one party has absolutely no negotiating power other than to accept it as-is or reject it completely. Courts have frequently found that when one party has an absolute advantage in setting the terms for a contract, the contract itself is inequitable and therefore prone to being unenforceable. The OP goes even further by retroactively trying to apply an adhesion contract to other software that was obtained prior to accessing the OP's software.

You could bolster the authority of your answer by linking to some cases when similar licences have been held to be unenforceable, and preferably from multiple jurisdictions.

@MadHatter, that's actually a good idea and I'll have to do a bit of research and update my post, probably later today or tomorrow. In the meantime here is an article that might prove enlightning. One aspect of the OP license is that it would force itself upon proprietary software, therefore taking away the legal rights of the copyright holder to that software. https://coruzant.com/opinion/contract-of-adhesion-demystified-key-things-to-know-before-signing/

In France, we have a similar concept of clauses abusives. When a clause of a contract restrict the rights of the customer beyond what the law explicitely allows, this clause is considered as non existent by any (French) court.

I don't want to make already existing software derived work of mine, that is not my intent.
GPL forces you to link only with other GPL or GPL-compatible software.
I want something similar, that aplies not only to linking, but also network communication, etc..

Right but the problem is that linking is usually an overt decision made by the software creators at time of software creation so they can reasonably foresee and accept all applicable licenses. Network connections are at runtime and involve decisions made by users of the software not the creators themselves and this would unavoidably impose legal liability on the creators for not considering your license due to actions made by their users not them. It’s a totally different thing and while IANAL I can’t imagine it could ever be enforced. It would cause chaos in the software industry as a model

I should never be guilty of violating your license because my user uses my software to connect to your service without my knowledge, and more importantly their doing so should not make my software a derivative work. And it looks like if you make network connections with your software define the connecting software as a derivative work, then that is exactly what you would be saying, albeit unintentionally. Why not just say “not for commercial use” anyway? I’ve seen lots of software do that, & it works as a pretty good commercial use deterrent.
